# How can I solve for a parameter in a cross distance function if I know the solution and other parameter in R?

Tags: r, vector, distance, solver

Using R, I want to solve for **s** given **x** and **y** in the following equation:

**y**=(**s**-**x**)'(**s**-**x**),

where **s** and **x** are 1x2 vectors. How may I do this? It is important to note that there will be many solutions for **s**, and I would like to obtain this entire set of solutions.

My work so far:

```
crossdist <- function(s,x){
  c1 <- complex(real=s[1], imaginary=s[2])
  c2 <- complex(real=x[1], imaginary=x[2])
  dist <- outer(c1,c2,function(z1,z2) Mod(z1-z2))
  dist
}


x=c(2,4)

y=.5

solcrossdist <- function(y,x) {
  return(polyroot(function(s) y - crossdist(s,x)))
}
```

However, this is not working properly. I feel like there is an extremely easy solution here that I'm missing.

**Update:**

Using the function provided by ThomasIsCoding, I used the following code to generate a pretty hefty set of solutions to this problem:

```
n=100000
s.save=rep(0,n)
for(k in 1:n){
  s.save[k]=s(k/100)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, `s` can be written as a function of `u` given `x` and `y` like below

```
s <- function(u,x = c(2,4), y = 0.5) c(x%*%c(1,1i)) + sqrt(y)*exp(1i*u)
```

Then you can try any real `u` for `s(u)` and check `y == Mod((2+4i)- s(u))**2`

Comment: Awesome- this looks pretty good! I updated my post to obtain many points. Just to clarify,  y == Mod((2+4i)- s(u))**2 should be TRUE, correct? How dd you derive this function?

Comment: Also, when I plot a lot of points, I'm surprised to see the set s takes on an oval shape around (2,4) with the wider axis occurring along the real number line. I expected this to be an oval. Do you have any idea why this is so?

Comment: @RonSnow The expression is an disk with center `x` and radius `sqrt(y)`. You can use polar coordinates to solve `s`

Comment: Okay, great thank you! That oval shape is really interesting.

Comment: what do you mean using polar coordinates to solve s?

Comment: @RonSnow `s-x` can be written as `s-x = sqrt(y)*exp(1i*u)` for any real `u`. Here is a link may help you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617322/the-equation-of-a-circle-on-a-complex-plane